# How to specify a .exe setup using visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

I'd like to ask how to make a .exe in VS2010. And also, how to manage the setup for this process. Such as how to determine the .exe's name and its location. Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you want to know these information within .exe itself?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I use Fortran. I have already make this clear. thank you all the same for your concern.

Answer (score 0):

The .exe's name can be setup by the following way: right click the project, click the properties, select C/C++ general, there are options of output directory and target name. by setting the two options, one can control the .exe's name and directory.